# How can to enable components in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

When I open any url I see always `UsersList.vue` component. Why? Because I include it in `App.vue`? If I changed it to `<router-view/>` I always see empty page. How can I fix it? And how can I make jump from `ListView` to `DetailView` through `router-link`

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import UsersList from '@/components/UsersList'
import UserDetail from '@/components/UserDetail'

Vue.use(Router)


export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/users/',
      name: 'UsersList',
      component: UsersList
    },
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      name: 'user_detail',
      component: UserDetail
    }
  ]
})
```

**main.js**

```
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VueAxios)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
}
</script>
```

**UsersList.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <tr v-for="user in usersList" :key="user.id">
        <td><router-link :to="{name:'user_detail',params:{id:user.id}}">{{ user.id }}</router-link></td>
      </tr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'UsersList',
  data() {
    return {
      usersList: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/')
      .then(response => (
        this.usersList = response.data.results
      ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must import your components (`UserList` and `UserDetail`) in your router configuration file (`index.js`).
After that you'll be able to use `<router-view>`

What is the url you intent to access ?
you must add a `base` in your Router :

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base:'/users',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/users/',
      name: 'UsersList',
      component: UsersList
    },
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      name: 'user_detail',
      component: UserDetail
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Don't work. I updated my code. I don't see `div id="app"` in the DOM

Comment: Import `App.vue` in your `main.js` too

Comment: `127.0.0.1:8000/users/` (it's a `Django` host)

Comment: you must put a base parameter

Comment: Thanx. I will try it later.